# Running keras.Sequential model on GPU

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, torch, kaggle

I am using Keras.Sequential model. I want to run it on GPU as the processing is taking a lot of time. I am using kaggle to run my code. I have set this configuration on Kaggle but whenever my model runs, it keeps using CPU and GPU usage does not changes.

```
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto( device_count = {'GPU': 1,'CPU': 56 } )
config = tf.compat.v1.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True )

sess = tf.compat.v1.Session(config=config) 
keras.backend.set_session(sess)
```

Here is my model class:

```
class DQNAgent(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
        self.memory = deque(maxlen=2000)
        self.gamma = 0.95  # discount rate
        self.epsilon = 1.0  # exploration rate
        self.epsilon_min = 0.01
        self.epsilon_decay = 0.995
        self.learning_rate = 0.001
        self.model = self._build_model()
    def _build_model(self):
        # Neural Net for Deep-Q learning Model
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(24, input_dim=100, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss='mse',
                      optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        
        return model
    def memorize(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))
    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.rand() <= self.epsilon:
            return random.randrange(self.action_size)
        act_values = self.model.predict(state)
        return np.argmax(act_values[0])  # returns action
    def replay(self, batch_size):
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                target = (reward + self.gamma *
                          np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
        if self.epsilon > self.epsilon_min:
            self.epsilon *= self.epsilon_decay
    def load(self, name):
        self.model.load_weights(name)
    def save(self, name):
        torch.save(name)
        print()
```

Comment: By default, keras model always run on GPU. The problem here is more like utilizaiton of GPU using your model. It depends on some factor: (i). efficient data pipeline (ii). model size etc. FYI, it makes no sense to use `nn.Module` instead of `keras.Model` if you use keras.

Comment: @M.Innat could you suggest some changes to my model class? I don't know much about utilizing a GPU under specific conditions

Comment: It's not starightfoward to give exact answer. Please search about how to utlize the gpu power in tf/keras with SO tag. Ideally, if the CPU is high and GPU is low, it typically means that the program tales much time on data processing. If possible use tf.data API for better input pipeline.